# Automatically import external library to source code and add external jar file (of library) to class path

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, command

I want to develop an application (or maybe eclipse plugin) which has following features:

- automatically insert some source code in a specify .java file class (add some methods or modify some original methods)
- automatically import/add external jar file to project class path (because the insert code using some external library) for compiling

To do above actions, I need to know the command line of eclipse to add external jar file to project class path and import library into source code (without Eclipse UI).

Is it possible?

Comment: You can do this without eclipse, simply using annotation processors embedded in the required jar. When the jar is in the classpath at compile time javac will pick up the annotation processor and write code - this does require the user to add annotations to the code and to manually add the jar. Although maven should take care of the latter. This has the advantage of being IDE independent.

Comment: Could you please give me more detail or some online tutorial for your suggestion?

Comment: [Here is the top result on Google](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/).